# List contains method returns false despite object having the same value - Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a 'cart to add' functionality. So there is a list named cartList which stores cartModel data. What I'm trying to do here is that once user has added the item to cartList, next time, when user tries to add the same item again, it would throw a message that item has already added to the cart

here is the code

```
ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          CartModel cartModel = CartModel(
                              productId: widget.productModel.productId,
                              productTitle: widget.productModel.productTitle,
                              productVariant: widget.productModel.productVariant,
                              productType: widget.productModel.productType,
                              images: widget.productModel.images,
                              options: widget.productModel.options,
                              selectedValue: selectedValue,
                              cartQuantity: 1
                          );
                          value.addProduct(cartModel, context);
                        },
                        child: Text('ADD TO CART', style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.white))
                    ),

  void addProduct(CartModel cartModel, BuildContext context){
    if(cartList.contains(cartModel)){ // returns false 
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('ALREADY ADDED TO THE CART', style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.white)), backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent));
    } else {
      cartList.add(cartModel);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('ADDED TO THE CART', style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.white)), backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent));
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Does your `CartModel` implement `operator ==`?  Otherwise `cartList.contains(cartModel)` will check for object *identity* (i.e., check for the exact same object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

contains uses == operator.

To check if an item exist in a list, you can use any operator. The correct way for your case would be:

```
bool exist = cartList.any((item) => {item.productId == cartModel.productId && item.productVariant == cartModel.productVariant})
if (exist) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('ALREADY ADDED TO THE CART', style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.white)), backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent));
} else {
    cartList.add(cartModel);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('ADDED TO THE CART', style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.white)), backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! So basically contains method were looking for same object but every time I was creating a new object of same values. Basically when it comes to contains, it doesn't matter if object properties has same values, it would still considered be different, right?

Comment: That's right. Do accept the answer if it solved problem :). Happy coding!

Comment: @HirakChhatbar do you have any alternative solution?